# Crontab Headaches when trying Python

Tags: python, unix, cron, zsh

I have successfully run a crontab but when I introduce a python script, nothing happens. I have verified that my python file works when run directly from the shell.

crontab is:

```
* * * * * /Users/myname/myzsh.zsh
```

where myzsh.zsh is:

```
#!/bin/zsh
/Users/mypath_to/python /Users/myname/testscript.py
```

Nothing happens

Comment: Is the script not running? Is it executable? Usually you'd provide the path to the shell before the path to the script.  Why not invoke the command directly using cron?

Comment: The .py script does not run. I have tried invoking the command directly in cron, but will try again

Comment: ok, I have tried crontab only, -  /path/to/python /path/to/.py.     still does not run the py

Comment: @Prolle: What is _Nothing happens_ supposed to mean? I suggest that inside your zsh-script, you turn on `-x`, and you also place a `/Users/mypath_to/python --version` before running you script, to verify that Python is basically working. Starting with this, you can then add further debugging commands.

Comment: Turns out cron itself had no permissions. I dragged and dropped it into the security section of preferences and voila!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out cron itself had no permissions. I dragged and dropped it into the security section of preferences and voila!

Answer (score 0):

This is a common enough `cron` gotcha.

Your environment is different between the interactive run and the cron run.
This causes the observed failure.

I assume you showed us `crontab -l` run as the same user
that ran the script interactively,
so we do not e.g. have a discrepancy with `root` running it under cron.

Your `$PWD`, present working directory, may matter.
Many cron jobs will do something like this:

```
cd some_dir && ./my_script.zsh
```

Quoting from the chapter 5 crontab man page:

> ... HOME, SHELL, and PATH may be overridden by settings in the crontab ...
>
> ... the environment handed to child processes is basically the one from /etc/rc.

You *really* want to embellish the environment before executing the script.

At a minimum I suspect you will need

```
env PYTHONPATH=. /Users/myname/myzsh.zsh
```

Many of *my* scripts set up a [conda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge) environment
before invoking cPython,
so `$PATH` is good.
Run a cron job of simply `env | sort >> /tmp/log.txt`
to see what PATH looks like by default.
Try using that PATH setting interactively and
likely you will notice the script fails the same as it does under cron.

You may find it convenient to bury `cd dir` and `export PATH=...`
within the myzsh.zsh script.

Consider running `python -m site` to help debug `sys.path` details.

---

Your script may be bailing out with a fatal error, a non-zero exit status.
As an aid to debugging, consider adding

```
MAILTO=prolle@some.email.provider.com
```

and then the `cron` daemon will send you the script's output,
if it produces more than zero lines on stdout + stderr.

Comment: tks - how do I find out what value I should use for PYTHONPATH (all i know is that it isnt the location of the python executable)

Comment: I gave you the value: simply `.` dot, denoting present working directory. And BTW you will definitely want cron to use a PWD that matches your interactive PWD. Python uses PWD plus a setting of `.` to correctly populate `sys.path`, which is what `import` relies on when it tries to find appropriate library files.

Comment: thanks. Not working either. I might try use conda envs

Comment: I have tried everything. This is driving me crazy, I have spent two complete days on this. I can't stop now!!

Comment: You didn't share any diagnostic information that cron is emailing you. Ok, let's assume your server is not correctly configured to send emails, so the MAILTO= isn't helping. You can obtain much the same thing in this way: * * * * * env PYTHONPATH=. /Users/myname/myzsh.zsh  >> /tmp/stdout.txt  2>> /tmp/stderr.txt

Comment: Let me just reinforce that it is almost a certainty that the PATH being used under cron is not good enough. Type `which python` interactively to learn where your favorite cPython interpreter is coming from. And then arrange for that directory to appear at the front of PATH within the cron environment. (I use conda, therefore /usr/bin is _always_ the wrong answer, I need an interpreter that knows where to find relevant deps.)